# Calling class vector after storing another class inside the vector

Tags: c++, c++11

heres my code, vector class lines2D

`vector<Line2D> lines2D;`

`lines2D.push_back(Line2D(Point2D(xAxis, yAxis), Point2D(zAxis, wAxis)));`

Stored data into the lines2D vector with another class Point2D constructor.

but now how do I call it to display the data inside the vector lines2D?

usually I would use
  `for(int i =0; i<lines2D.size();i++) { cout << lines2D.at(i) << endl; }`

But with the another class method in it i was not able to figure out the syntax.

I want to get results like

`line2D.pt1.getX(), line2D.pt1.getY() line2D.pt2.getY(), line2D.pt2.getY()`

basically to get the Point2D(x, y) Point2D(x, y) that is stored in my Line2D class.

Answer (score 0):

Make  a function inside your class to print the values of your class variable as elements in your vector Lines2D are objects of Line2D + you haven't shared your code so i am assuming you have a method to get the xAxis, yAxis and zAxis variables from your Point2D class.